# Infopath 2007 form's controls resized after migration to sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath-2007

I recently migrated my MOSS 2007 application to share point 2010 which included browser based info-path form filling feature. The controls in the form look compressed and re-sized, and effectively renders without the desired functionality.

Is there anything I can do to get the form back to its normal view?

Thanks a million in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2010 rendering is different from MOSS 2007. I had to included

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

in my aspx page that hosted the xml form view. This worked for me!